# Webform what is format required to prepopulate datetime element

Tags: 8, webforms

Sending default date format (medium) from VIEW rewrite results link, URL adding
?apptdatet={{ field_apptdatet }}
This never fills the webform datetime field. The value is shown in the url as medium formatted date. day mm dd yyyy hh:mm:ss
On the webform the apptdatet field shows the correct format mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss, the value is always blank however.
in the view apptdatet shows as Mon 05-14-2018 15:30
Does anyone know what Webform is looking for?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use an ISO date.

```
?apptdate=2018-06-13T01:01:01-0400
```

Comment: Excellent, I will now try to figure out how to convert the default drupal date in the view field to the ISO format in the URL

Comment: The issue continues at: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/263915/how-to-remove-the-added-underscore-views-adds-to-rewritten-link-d8