# How do I remove the underscore a view adds to a rewritten link?

Tags: views, 8

I am using fields, one has a link, rewriting the link as shown below sending the datetime to webform in the URL. All fields display as they should. When hovering over the link, the URL shows extra space at the end of each field as an underscore as follows. The underscore is not in the datetime field.

> 2018-05-14T15:39:15-0400_

As seen above the underscore is added. Webform wont prepopulate the datetime field element with the underscore. When manually writing the value, webform correctly prepopulates my webform.
The link is `/appt_testform?apptdatet={{ field_apptdatet }}&body={{ body }}`, which becomes `/appt_testform?apptdatet=2018-07-15T18%3A00%3A00-0400_&amp;body=Testing%20the%20appt%2C%20test%20and%20recommend`. The underscore after 0400 should not be there.

I see an underscore is added to other fields, which accept values where the datetime will not. I am trying to do this without using `hook_form_alter()`.

---

After testing on 5 servers using different 8.x versions
When importing using feeds module CSV file, 
If the content field is date and time..imported using feeds then View linked to webform to prepopulate it will add the underscore as shown in the original question.
If a field is timestamp (unix number in CSV) after importing, the view rewrite results link does not have the underscore added. I don't know why, however, my site works using the timestamp field type. On all the servers.

Comment: If you switch to the Drupal default theme "Bartik" does the same behavior occur there?

Comment: using Bartik theme already.  Default.  I am using only & between the fields. If there is a more correct method I could try that as well.

Comment: Are you able to replicate this on a fresh Drupal install? Can you provide a screenshot of  your re-write?

Comment: You are so right. Laptop version is 8.5.1 and this doesn't happen. Unable to see version of internal network version until tomorrow. Awesome.

Comment: the Drupal Core version it's happening on is 8.5.4, will try on another server without a few modules.. I'll track it down

Comment: CONFIRMED, 2 different servers d8 ver 8.5.4 php 7.x both add the underscore to values separated by &.  This goes unanswered at this point

Comment: Switch those two to 8.5.1 if it doesn't happen there than it must be a Drupal Core bug.

Comment: upgraded the laptop with win10 wamp d8 8.5.1 to 8.5.4 and it works fine.  Now back to wondering where to look next.  upgraded linux server to d8 8.5.5 today, still puts the extra space (underscore) at the end of each value. The other server is hosted by godaddy and is running 8.5.4.  Laptop running win10 Lampp is only one that works.

Comment: Is all of the Drupal files & DB exactly identical in all of these servers? If yes, then it could be an .htaccess rule that is adding the underscores.

Comment: I just had this issue and I'm on Drupal 9.1.3, still no resolution.

Answer (score -1):

This issue happens when the field value is rendered with HTML (which is appended by Drupal date formats).

In your View, edit your time field and make sure to use Custom formatter rather than any of the predefined ones, and provide the custom pattern in 'Date/time format' field. And then underscore should go. [Check this useful answer](https://www.drupal.org/project/views/issues/1308078#comment-5146904).

In my case I was struggling with underscore appended after Year value (mysirte.com/tag/1994_), and when I created custom format and used 'Y' the underscore disappeared, see picture:
[image]